# how to untie Java EE tutorial examples from NetBeans and use them with Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I am trying to go through the Java EE 6 Tutorial samples with Eclipse.
It seems it will be very hard.

I just started.
I found the Hello and Hello1 samples cannot be used in Eclipse directly.
Other than these NetBeans specific files/folders,
the java files are under "src/java/" folder but the "java" folder is NOT a package name. Eclipse doesn't like this structure.

Is there an easy way to convert these samples to be usable with Eclipse?
Are there any other Java EE sample sets can be used in Eclipse?

Comment: All the Java EE 6 and 7 tutorials I've followed were made using Eclipse and JBoss/Wildfly instead of NetBeans and GlassFish and worked. Note: use maven, it will be better for project structure across IDEs.

Comment: Eclipse and JBoss is my setting. I will try maven then. thanks.

Comment: @Luiggi, do you have the link? cannot find Maven version of it.

Answer (score 1):

Install Maven plugin for eclipse (**ME2Eclipse**) or use an Eclipse version, which already contains the plugin like **Eclipse for Java EE Developers**.

Then import the hello1 example as **existing maven project**.

In Eclipse you can build and deploy the project with **Run maven install**.

If you don't use maven, you have to set the source folder in Java Build path as mentioned from DwB in the post before.

A detailed description for your first project you will have in the **Firstcup** example installed with the glassfish server.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse does not care which folder is used for the java source;
however, you will have to tell eclipse which folder to use by choosing the source folders in the project properties!Java Build Path!Source tab
(open project properties, select the Java Build path option on the left side, select the Source tab).